# Laravel Login Always Returns false

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a login system but it always returns the wrong details, even though in my database the email and password of my text exist, I can see them in phpMyAdmin. I'm aware of the existence of PHP Artisan Auth but I have to write the code alone this once.

I have created 3 methods in my controller checkLogin(), successLogin() (maybe I should delete this as it might be pointless) and logout().

I strongly believe that my issue is located in the routes. Just a heads up, all the files i.e. index.blade.php & login.blade.php are located under: `views/users/`.

```
<?php

function checkLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3'
    ]);

    $user_data = array(
        'email' => $request->get('email'),
        'password' => $request->get('password')
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($user_data)) {
        return redirect('/users');
    } else {
        return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
    }
}

function successLogin()
{
    return view('/users');
}

function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();

    return redirect('users.index');
}
```

**Blade**

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    <style type="text/css">
        .box {
            width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container box">
        <h3 align="center">Please Login To Continue</h3><br/>
        @if(isset(Auth::user()->email))
            <script>window.location = "/users";</script>
        @endif
        @if ($message = Session::get('error'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </div>
        @endif

        @if (count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif

        <form method="post" action="{{ url('/login/checklogin') }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Enter Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Enter Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**Routes**

```
Route::post('/login/checklogin', 'UserController@checklogin');
Route::get('/login/successlogin', 'UserController@successlogin');
Route::get('/login/logout', 'UserController@logout');
Route::get('/login',function () {
    return view('/users/login');
});
```

Comment: Is the password encrypted in the database? If so, you should use `'password' => bcrypt($request->get('password'))`. Anyway, have you checked what's being returned by your `$user_data` or `Auth::attempt($user_data)` with `dd()`?

Comment: No I am not encrypting the password.  
I Just used dd and got exactly what I have inputed :
  "email" => "testemail@mail.com"
  "password" => "1234"


returns false with correct input

Comment: Check your model /app/User.php if it's has same credential with your controller

Comment: @JesseJay I dont understand what you want me to do,
But I have a question If I dont hash the password. when the Auth:: comes and wants to check will it not search my pass as hashed to a non hashed password? cause from what I am seeing is that its doing it should be doing it automatically when I am pressing Login. and if thats the case then its correct when it returns false since I never hashed the password before I saved it. so if it looks for a hashed one when I try to login i will get an error right ?

Comment: and yes that was the case.. you need to Hash the password before doing anythign else

Comment: I believe that `Auth::attempt` hashes the provided password so you really need to save the hashed password in the database, or just make your own authentication function.